# Generating pseudorandom numbers drawn from a uniform distribution

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm looking to build a function in Clojure that outputs m x n matrix of pseudorandom numbers drawn from the open interval (0,1). The specified inputs would be the row dimension m and column dimension n. I have familiarity with constructed matrices, nested vectors, in Clojure but have never generated random (psuedo) numbers before. My first guess, if starting from scratch, would use modular arithmetic to pump out inputs for the m x n matrix. Is this the easiest way to implement this idea?

Comment: This is the first place I have asked.

Comment: It's a good question, but that seems like a violation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and commonsense use of search engines

Comment: The [Clojure cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet) is another good first-stop reference.

Comment: If you decide that instead of a uniform distribution, you want something else, I would take a look to see what's available in Incanter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `(rand)` generates a number from the uniform between 0 and 1. So with:

```
(for [row (range m)]
  (for [column (range n)]
    (rand)))
```

there is no need to implement your own generator.

Answer (score 2):

Using `core.matrix`, you can use the `emap` function to do this:

```
(emap (fn [_] (rand)) (new-array [5 4]))
```

By default this returns a matrix of nested Clojure vectors, e.g.:

```
[[0.3325314113549507 0.7148578741930893 0.1786957191876699  0.46844096741466656]
 [0.8216388560276083 0.3733963694778344 0.7311554209845575  0.05163744870109632]
 [0.7838218008385947 0.8751976936581514 0.16056093051752107 0.5836745330219952]
 [0.6137578842075752 0.9735681676917135 0.30319026184660314 0.19757184630153146]   
 [0.6216442815557222 0.795080498020428  0.685714719411497   0.1567460494112074]]
```